# unexpected indentation in coffee-script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've been trying to convert all my coffee-scripts into a bundle using webpack.

But I am stuck at one part.

It was giving following error

> error: unexpected indentation
>
> super

I've a small snippet of the the code.

```
class p
  check: (x,y,z) ->
    if x and y
        super
    else
        if y
            x = y
        else
            super
```

I am able to reproduce this error when I've checked it in http://coffeescript.org/

However, http://js2.coffee/ was able to convert it to javascript.

Go to the above sites and paste the above code snippet there.

I've also tried to convert it to different online tools.

[Tool 1](https://decaffeinate-project.org/repl/#?useCS2=false&useJSModules=false&loose=false&evaluate=true&stage=full&code=class%20p%0A%20%20check%3A%20(x%2Cy%2Cz)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20x%20and%20y%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20y%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the problem lies with the version.

[coffeescript.org/try](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20p%0A%20%20check%3A%20(x%2Cy%2Cz)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20x%20and%20y%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20super%20arguments...%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20y%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20y%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super%20arguments...) uses coffeescript 2.X.X (currently 2.2.4)

Coffeescript 2 compiles down to modern JS as supported by Node 7.6+
This means that Coffeescript classes now compile to ES6 style classes rather than prototypes. This has brought some limitations resulting in changes in Coffeescript 2.

From the [coffeescript 2 announcement](http://coffeescript.org/announcing-coffeescript-2/) :

> In CoffeeScript 2, “bare” super (calling super without arguments) is now no longer allowed, and one must use super() or super arguments... instead.

You need to change `super` to explicitly pass all the arguments to the overwritten method : `super arguments...`

```
class p
  check: (x,y,z) ->
    if x and y
      super arguments...
    else
      if y
        x = y
      else
        super arguments...
```

Comment: Where did you get time machine? Who is the president of US in your time? Does US still exists? Does the Earth exist or all survivors migrated to Mars? I'm asking all of this, because current Coffeescript version is 2.3.1

Comment: @metalim My bad - that was a typo. It was 2.2.4 at the time of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to versions of coffee-script.

In http://coffeescript.org/, it has the latest version,

while in http://js2.coffee/, it has `version 1.9.2`

when I downgrade the version, I was able to resolve my problem.

For current requirement, I have downgraded it and it is the solution to my Problem.

If anyone has a different answer please post your answer.

Thanks